# Importing from a different folder

Tags: python

I have two python files in two different folders:

```
file_1.py in C:\Users\user\Google Drive\Prime\Engr\analysis
file_2.py in C:\Users\user\Google Drive\Prime\Engr\analysis\Machine_learning
```

I want to import a function `func_name` from `file_1.py` into `file_2.py`, I have tried a lot of the proposed variations in related questions but nothing seems to work for me, what is the right way to do this?

Comment: "I have tried a lot of the proposed variations" - what _did_ you try? And how exactly did it not work?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the space in 'Google Drive', then in file_2.py:

```
from .file_1 import func_name
```

Also, make sure you are avoiding circular imports.

Comment: It doesn't, I get this error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__main__.Twenty_one_db'; '__main__' is not a package`